# How would I make a TcpClient request per item in a futures Stream?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I have a concept project where the client sends a server a number (`PrimeClientRequest`), the server computes if the value is prime or not, and returns a response (`PrimeClientResponse`). I want the client to be a simple CLI which prompts the user for a number, sends the request to the server, and displays the response. Ideally I want to do this using `TcpClient` from Tokio and Streams from Futures-Rs.

I've written a Tokio server using services and I want to reuse the same `codec` and `proto` for the client.

Part of the client is a function called `read_prompt` which returns a `Stream`. Essentially it is an infinite loop at which each iteration reads in some input from `stdin`.

Here's the relevant code:

**main.rs**

```
use futures::{Future, Stream};
use std::env;
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use tokio_prime::protocol::PrimeClientProto;
use tokio_prime::request::PrimeRequest;
use tokio_proto::TcpClient;
use tokio_service::Service;

mod cli;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    let addr_string = env::args().nth(1).unwrap_or("127.0.0.1:8080".to_string());
    let remote_addr = addr_string.parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();

    println!("Connecting on {}", remote_addr);
    let tcp_client = TcpClient::new(PrimeClientProto).connect(&remote_addr, &handle);

    core.run(tcp_client.and_then(|client| {
        client
            .call(PrimeRequest { number: Ok(0) })
            .and_then(|response| {
                println!("RESP = {:?}", response);
                Ok(())
            })
    })).unwrap();
}
```

**cli.rs**

```
use futures::{Future, Sink, Stream};
use futures::sync::mpsc;
use std::{io, thread};
use std::io::{Stdin, Stdout};
use std::io::prelude::*;

pub fn read_prompt() -> impl Stream<Item = u64, Error = ()> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(1);

    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let thread_tx = tx.clone();

        let input = prompt(io::stdout(), io::stdin()).unwrap();
        let parsed_input = input
            .parse::<u64>()
            .map_err(|_| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "invalid u64"));

        thread_tx.send(parsed_input.unwrap()).wait().unwrap();
    });

    rx
}

fn prompt(stdout: Stdout, stdin: Stdin) -> io::Result<String> {
    let mut stdout_handle = stdout.lock();
    stdout_handle.write(b"> ")?;
    stdout_handle.flush()?;

    let mut buf = String::new();
    let mut stdin_handle = stdin.lock();
    stdin_handle.read_line(&mut buf)?;

    Ok(buf.trim().to_string())
}
```

With the code above, the client sends a single request to the server before the client terminates. I want to be able to use the stream generated from `read_prompt` to provide input to the `TcpClient` and make a request per item in the stream. How would I go about doing this?

The full code can be found at [joshleeb/tokio-prime](https://github.com/joshleeb/tokio-prime).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have come up with (so far) has been to use the [`LoopFn`](https://docs.rs/futures/*/futures/future/struct.LoopFn.html) in the Future-Rs crate. It's not ideal as a new connection still has to be made but it is at least a step in the right direction.

**main.rs**

```
use futures::{future, Future};
use std::{env, io};
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio_core::reactor::{Core, Handle};
use tokio_prime::protocol::PrimeClientProto;
use tokio_prime::request::PrimeRequest;
use tokio_proto::TcpClient;
use tokio_service::Service;

mod cli;

fn handler<'a>(
    handle: &'a Handle, addr: &'a SocketAddr
) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + 'a {
    cli::prompt(io::stdin(), io::stdout())
        .and_then(move |number| {
            TcpClient::new(PrimeClientProto)
                .connect(addr, handle)
                .and_then(move |client| Ok((client, number)))
        })
        .and_then(|(client, number)| {
            client
                .call(PrimeRequest { number: Ok(number) })
                .and_then(|response| {
                    println!("{:?}", response);
                    Ok(())
                })
        })
        .or_else(|err| {
            println!("! {}", err);
            Ok(())
        })
}

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    let addr_string = env::args().nth(1).unwrap_or("127.0.0.1:8080".to_string());
    let remote_addr = addr_string.parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();

    println!("Connecting on {}", remote_addr);

    let client = future::loop_fn((), |_| {
        handler(&handle, &remote_addr)
            .map(|_| -> future::Loop<(), ()> { future::Loop::Continue(()) })
    });

    core.run(client).ok();
}
```

**cli.rs**

```
use futures::prelude::*;
use std::io;
use std::io::{Stdin, Stdout};
use std::io::prelude::*;

#[async]
pub fn prompt(stdin: Stdin, stdout: Stdout) -> io::Result<u64> {
    let mut stdout_handle = stdout.lock();
    stdout_handle.write(b"> ")?;
    stdout_handle.flush()?;

    let mut buf = String::new();
    let mut stdin_handle = stdin.lock();
    stdin_handle.read_line(&mut buf)?;

    parse_input(buf.trim().to_string())
}

fn parse_input(s: String) -> io::Result<u64> {
    s.parse::<u64>()
        .map_err(|_| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "invalid u64"))
}
```